# Behat SpecBDD and StoryBDD basic featured symfony2 example application

Tags: php, symfony, bdd, behat, phpspec

I'm start learning the tools for Behaviour Driven Development in PHP like SpecBDD and StoryBDD with Symfony2.

The official documentations of these tools are excelent, but not enough to start learning for me (and I hope for other beginners in this subject).

So... Is there any basic featured (I mean basic user authentication / authorization, basic crud of any other model and a few static pages) symfony2 example application developed with these tools?

I want to know for example how to write phpspec for the form types and other symfony's stuff

Comment: You can take a look at Sylius, which is build with Behat and PHPspec: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius However, questions asking for external resources are off-topic for the StackExchange network, including StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the [Full stack BDD talk](http://www.slideshare.net/marcello.duarte/full-stack-bdd-for-symfony2) talk by [_md](https://twitter.com/_md) and [everzet](https://twitter.com/everzet) here: https://github.com/everzet/fullstack-bdd-sflive2012/commits/master.

Everzet's wrapup is here: http://everzet.com/post/31581124270/fullstack-bdd-2012-wrapup